# Cant find video downloaded with selenium on Heroku - Django

Tags: django, selenium, file, heroku, celery

I have the following application I'm working on but I have an error that I can't figure out what I should do.

The application is as follows the user adds a link to a video, the task is sent to celery via redis, celery downloads that video and saves it to media/AppVimeoApp/videos/.mp4, then displays it on a page with src="media\AppVimeoApp\videos....mp4".

This app works fine locally, on heroku however the task shows me as successful but the video is nowhere to be found, I just need it temporarily.

tasks.py

```
@shared_task
def download_video():
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.binary_location = str(os.getenv('GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN'))
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')    
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-software-rasterizer')
    chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 4.2.1; Microsoft; Lumia 640 XL LTE) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10166")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')

    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "download.default_directory": f"{settings.MEDIA_ROOT}\\AppVimeoApp\\videos",
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
        "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False,
        "safebrowsing.enabled": False
        }
    )

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=str(os.getenv('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH')), chrome_options=chrome_options)

    driver.get('videolink')

    time.sleep(5)

    while True:
        try:
            driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div[2]/div[1]/a').click()
            break
        except:
            time.sleep(1)
            continue

    time.sleep(5)

    return ("Downloaded")
```

I am very grateful if you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: "but the video is nowhere to be found"—what are you trying to do with the video after downloading it, and how? I don't see any code that tries to access the file after it is downloaded.

Comment: Hi @Chris, i try to put it on a page html

```
<video width="530" height="440" controls="" autoplay="">
            <source src="media\AppVimeoApp\videos\8b6344025043413ea92ff4e1b48871b7.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
        </video>
```

Comment: Ah, I see. You're downloading with Celery. Presumably that's done as a separate process. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution

Heroku use linux so download directory need be

```
"download.default_directory": f"{settings.MEDIA_ROOT}/AppVimeoApp/videos",
```

And on windows

```
"download.default_directory": f"{settings.MEDIA_ROOT}\\AppVimeoApp\\videos",
```

Answer (score 1):

> celery downloads that video and saves it

That won't work on Heroku.

Each dyno has its own isolated [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Whatever process is running Celery (often a `worker` process) will save the file to its own filesystem, which is different from the filesystem seen by your `web` dynos.

Furthermore, all of these filesystems lose changes whenever their dyno restarts. This happens unpredictably and frequently—[at least once per day](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3). So saving files this way isn't a great solution on Heroku even from a single dyno.

A better solution would be to save the video to a third-party object store like Amazon S3 or Azure Blob Storage. Heroku has [documentation for using S3 this way](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3). Since you want to process the file you'll need to do what Heroku calls a [pass-through upload](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3#pass-through-uploads):

> In a pass-through upload, a file uploads to your app, which in turn uploads it to S3. This method enables you to perform preprocessing on user uploads before you push them to S3.

You'll have to do the image overlay on the same worker where you download the file due to the aforementioned filesystem isolation.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for the message but if I save to S3 how will I be able to retrieve the video to process it? Because the app will retrieve the video and combine it with an image and that's why I needed the video to be in files.

Comment: You'd have to download it as you currently are, then process it from the same worker process, then upload it to S3. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @Chris for your answer, now it is clearer to me what to do, but I have another question? That I didn't find in the heroku documentation, how can I access the video from the worker before uploading to S3, I tried with "clip = VideoFileClip('media/AppVimeoApp/videos/8b6344025043413ea92ff4e1b48871b7.mp4')" but I get the error could not be found!\nPlease check that you entered the correct path.'

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem would be there, @dani99. But that's a relative path. Are you sure that's how it should look? In your question you use `settings.MEDIA_ROOT`—shouldn't you do the same here?

Comment: Yes, i dont understand why @Chris. I save the video on f"{settings.MEDIA_ROOT}\\AppVimeoApp\\video" and i try to get the video from the f"{settings.MEDIA_ROOT}/AppVimeoApp/video/de07fb663fbf470ead9b3f9509c2bf96.mp4" and i got the error OSError('MoviePy error: the file /app/media/AppVimeoApp/video/de07fb663fbf470ead9b3f9509c2bf96.mp4 could not be found!\nPlease check that you entered the correct path.'). The video name its correct.

Comment: I think i found the problem @Chris, i saw heroku save files on dyno, and i have 2 dynos one web and one worker, probably heroku save the video on worker dyno. Do you know how can i acces it?

Comment: @dani99, that's part of what I said in my answer: "Each dyno has its own isolated ephemeral filesystem. Whatever process is running Celery (often a `worker` process) will save the file to its own filesystem, which is different from the filesystem seen by your `web` dynos… You'll have to do the image overlay on the same worker where you download the file due to the aforementioned filesystem isolation."